# Replace values with numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a a dataframe, which has three possible values, "Up", "Down" or NA.

dim(df) = 61,5

I want to replace all "Up" values by +2

All "Down" values by -2

All NA values by 0

I have created the following function but I keep on getting this error:

```
Binaryexpress <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:5){
  j<-1
while(j<= 61){
  if (x[j,i] == "Down"){
    x[j,i] <- -2
    j <- j+1

  } else if(x[j,i] == "Up"){
    x[j,i] <- 2
    j<- j+1

  }else if(is.na(x[j,i]) == TRUE){
    x[j,i] <- 0
    j<- j+1

  }
  i<- i+1
}
}
}

 Error in if (x[j, i] == "Down") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have tried other methods also on the forum, such as -> df[df == NA] <- 0 , but this has not worked either.

EDIT::

Dataframe looks like this:

```
 x1    x2    x3    x4    x5
y Up  Down   NA    NA    Up
k Down NA    Up    NA    NA
l .     .    .     .     .
m .     .    .     .     .
.
.
```

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set?

Comment: @Merik just did

Comment: A silly approach: `df[] <- match(unlist(df), c("Down", NA, "Up"))*2L - 4L`

Comment: @Frank can't make this work, could you add as answer?

Comment: @zx8 Ok, posted. I guess it might not work with factors. I only tested it with code from Matt's answer that uses character columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any of that.

```
db[db=="Up"] <- 2
db[db=="Down"] <- -2
db[is.na(db)] <- 0
```

Basically, you're searching your database (which I called db) for "Up", "Down", or NAs, and assigning 2, -2, and 0 respectively.

This leaves you with all characters, so you do this:

```
db<-as.data.frame(sapply(db,as.numeric))
```

In your comment you said it gives you a factor error - that means your df is all factors. Fix that by starting out with this:

```
db<-as.data.frame(sapply(db,as.character),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: This is not exactly correct, because the data type of that variable will remain "character" and will not change to "numeric" which I think is what is desired.

Comment: I have tried this already, but i get the following error: 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = 2) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: That is because of the same problem I just mentioned.

Comment: @doviod You might add `db[] <- lapply(db, as.character)` before and `db[] <- lapply(db, as.integer)` after your solution.

Comment: markus - yeah, I didn't realize it was all factors until I saw Omar's comment. I prefer to take away the factors before I begin working on it. Hate factors. :)

Comment: will try it this way

Answer (score 2):

using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x1 = sample(c('up', 'down', NA), 61, replace = TRUE),
                 x2 = sample(c('up', 'down', NA), 61, replace = TRUE),
                 x3 = sample(c('up', 'down', NA), 61, replace = TRUE),
                 x4 = sample(c('up', 'down', NA), 61, replace = TRUE),
                 x5 = sample(c('up', 'down', NA), 61, replace = TRUE))


first convert everything to string:

df %>%
    mutate_all(as.character) %>%
    replace(., . == 'up', 2) %>%
    replace(., . == 'down', -2) %>%
    replace(., is.na(.), 0)
```

Comment: If you're using the 'verse, case_when also seems to fit https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.6/topics/case_when

Answer (score 2):

If you have character data (eg, as in MattW's answer), this silly approach works:

```
df[] <- match(unlist(df), c("Down", NA, "Up"))*2L - 4L
```

It matches Down, NA, Up to 1, 2, 3, respectively, then does arithmetic to map 1, 2, 3 to -2, 0, 2.

I don't think this is a good way to arrange data, though. When many (or all) columns contain related data, it's better to use a matrix or put the data into "long form".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an even cleaner solution, using `vapply` so you can see exactly what is going on:

```
db <- data.frame(
  x1 = as.factor(c('Up', 'Up', 'Down', NA)),
  x2 = as.factor(c('Up', 'Down', NA, 'Down'))
  )

numerize <- function(x){
  ifelse(is.na(x), 0, ifelse(x == 'Up', 2, ifelse(x == 'Down', -2, NA)))
}

db$x1 <- vapply(db$x1, numerize, 0)
db$x2 <- vapply(db$x2, numerize, 0)
```

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: Note that I am intentionally not using `dplyr` or `data.table` even though they provide more convenient ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to base R, you write a function which does the replacement for one column and then apply that function to all columns.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(c("Up", "Down", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = sample(c("Up", "Down", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  x3 = sample(c("Up", "Down", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  x4 = sample(c("Up", "Down", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  x5 = sample(c("Up", "Down", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

recode_vals <- function(df, col) {
  df[[col]] <- ifelse(is.na(df[col]), 0,
                              ifelse(df[col] == "Up", 2, -2))
  df[[col]]
}

df3 <- sapply(colnames(df), function(nm) recode_vals(df, nm))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use factors converted to numeric with appropriate transformation: :

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x1 = sample(c('Up', 'Down', NA), 5, replace = TRUE),
                 x2 = sample(c('Up', 'Down', NA), 5, replace = TRUE),
                 x3 = sample(c('Up', 'Down', NA), 5, replace = TRUE))
df
# x1   x2   x3
# 1   Up <NA>   Up
# 2 Down <NA>   Up
# 3 Down Down <NA>
# 4 <NA> Down Down
# 5   Up   Up <NA>

df[] <- lapply(df,function(x) (as.numeric(factor(x,c("Down", NA, "Up"),exclude=NULL))-2)*2)
df
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  2  0  2
# 2 -2  0  2
# 3 -2 -2  0
# 4  0 -2 -2
# 5  2  2  0
```